# Similar to inversion, what other geometric transformations have been used to prove theorems easily?

Tags: geometry

I just learned of the proof of Ptlomey's theorem and was just amazed by it [(see here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJOuzqu3MUQ) and it made me wonder, are there other such transformations which gives out difficult geometrical results easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important transformation in projective geometry is changing points into lines and vice versa to get dual theorems. [For example](https://staff.imsa.edu/%7Efogel/ModGeo/PDF/25%20More%20Dual%20Theorems.pdf), once you've proved [Ceva's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem), its dual, [Menelaus's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem), follows.